# Tika: What's OOXMLParser meant for?

Tags: java, apache-tika

Currently, we are getting mime types using this code:

```
public String getMimeType(ByteArrayInputStream bais) {

    Detector detector = new DefaultDetector();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

    try {
        MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(TikaInputStream.get(bais), metadata);
        String mimetype = mediaType.toString();

        //================================
        if (null != mimetype && mimetype.contains("ooxml")) {
            BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
            ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();

            OOXMLParser msofficeparser = new OOXMLParser();
            msofficeparser.parse(bais, handler, metadata, pcontext);
            return metadata.get(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE);
        }
        //================================

        return mimetype;
    } catch (TikaException | IOException | SAXException e) {
        throw new DocumentException("Unable to find out MimeType ", e);
    }
}
```

We need only to get mime type. The question is: Is it necessary to use this additional code between `//===========` in order to get it?

We've tried to comment this code, and it seems it picks the correct mime type, but we don't understand what this code snippet is meant for.

I hope I've explained well...

We've detected that if this specific code snippet is commented, the